# Why MySQLdb gets the duplicated db connections

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm using MySQLdb as my python-mysql connection. My test code as following:

```
for i in range(6):
   db = MySQLdb.connect('localhost','user','passwd','test'))
   print db
```

I got the results as following:

```
_mysql.connection open to localhost at 1bba010
_mysql.connection open to localhost at 1c1ba90
_mysql.connection open to localhost at **1c34fa0**
_mysql.connection open to localhost at **1c3cdb0**
_mysql.connection open to localhost at **1c34fa0**
_mysql.connection open to localhost at **1c3cdb0**
```

You would find the last two connection objects are duplicated. This is a problem when I'm using multiple-process to query mysql. i.e, when one process has finished job then it would close the connection while others were still using the same db connection, how should I fix this issue please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The re-use of memory locations is not a problem.  In your test program, you are closing the connection and releasing the object.  That means the memory is freed, and available for re-use.  Then you make a new connection object, and the memory location is used again.

The addresses alternate because object 1 isn't freed until after object 2 has been created, object 2 isn't freed until object 3 has been created, and so on.

Comment: I remove the db.close(), I still get the same connection object.

Comment: I'm using multiple-process to query mysql, each process I created one new connection, but they have duplicates. It cause exception when the same connection was closed by the earlier process. I'm so confused, is there a default connection pool in MySQLdb? if so I really don't wanna use it.

Comment: The db.close was not the interesting part.  the connection is probably closed implicitly when the object is released.